# About the word 地図

Tags: word-requests

こんにちはー。

私はこの間、春の夜の星座を描いてみました。きれいな形が好きで、覚えたいんです。でも、この絵は、「空の地図」と呼んだらいいですか？

地図 = 地 + 図 ですが、空は、ちがいます。そういえば、「空の図」でいいですか？

どんな言葉が合っていますか？教えてください(^-^)

日本語で質問してみましたが、間違いを許してください(*´∀｀*)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ズバリ「星図」という言葉があります。小学校の理科の授業で習う言葉です。

[https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/星図](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%98%9F%E5%9B%B3)

Comment: ありがとうございます。私の描いた星図は、たとえば、not-to-scaleですw。まだ星図ですか？よくない星図だけですね、と思いますw。

Comment: @requiredandshown Just as 地図/map can refer to both professionally-designed ones and handwritten ones, 星図 can refer to both scientific ones and handwritten ones as long as it's mainly for showing where in the sky you can find a certain celestial body.